# Is there a problem with ksoap2 and soap Version 12?

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I tested calling a soap  12 webservices with ksoap2. 
I used this code to call the webservice:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, NAME);
request.addProperty("id", ID);
request.addProperty("name", "test@test.de");
request.addProperty("pw", "password");
request.addProperty("listid", 501);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

AndroidHttpTransport client = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
try {
   client.call(NAMESPACE + NAME, envelope);
   Object response = envelope.getResponse();
} catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "IO Problem", e);
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
   Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Parser Problem", e);
}
```

I now get the following exception:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException:expected: START_TAG {http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG <{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}soapenv:Envelope>@1:114 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44f28a80)
```

Is this a problem of the server response or is there something wrong in my code so far? It seems that other users have the same problem. If I change the Envelope to SoapEnvelope.VER11 I get a step further (I get an access denied response from the soap server probably because of a wrong URL) maybe there is additional info missing to create a VER12 envelope.

Comment: What do you mean you get a step further with v11? Do you actually get a proper response back?

Comment: I get a permission denied from the soap service. This seems to be a problem with the url im using and not the ksoap library.

Comment: PermissionDenied is 99% because you didn't provide <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> in your AndroidManifest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the various options for your envelope to see what the services expects?

E.g. you can set

```
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.headerOut = security; // this is an Element[] created before
envelope.encodingStyle = SoapEnvelope.ENC;
envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
envelope.implicitTypes = false;
```

and a bunch more. Check out the javadoc?

Also make sure to use the latest release of the `ksoap2-android` project to get a bunch of fixes that are not in the normal `sourceforge` project.

Comment: Problem still not solved but the bounty is about to expire. So I will give it to you as a reward for your efforts on ksoap on android. Thanks for the only working solution to communicate with a soap API.

Comment: Thx. It might be a case of trying to use a different configuration on the server side. Hopefully you have control over it.

Comment: Thank you! really helped :D finally!
By the way, what helped me was changing SOAP version from SOAP12 to SOAP11 + these settings provided by Manfred Moser

Answer (score 1):

What I did to make this work was use version 11, and it worked fine for me :-)

```
        // Request model
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, Metodo);

        // Envelop model
        SoapSerializationEnvelope sobre = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        sobre.dotNet = true;
        sobre.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        // Transport model
        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(url);

        // Let's call it :)
        transporte.call(accionSoap, sobre);

        //Result
        SoapPrimitive resultado = (SoapPrimitive) sobre.getResponse();

        tv.setText("" + resultado.toString());
```

My variables:

```
private static final String accionSoap = "http://tempuri.org/ServicioAndroid";
private static final String Metodo = "ServicioAndroid";
private static final String namespace = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String url = "http://192.168.1.33/AutoEPOC_H/WS/WSAutoEPOC.asmx";
```

This Web Service was created usin dotNet. You can check your method, action, namespace and URL by running your Web Service using IIS.

If you understand Spanish, you can check these links:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MMByNiwqMc

http://programa-con-google.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-como-consumir-un-servicio-web.html

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try `VR11` and replace your

```
Object response = envelope.getResponse();
```

with

```
SoapObject reponse=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use ksoap2 ver11 only... still it gives me an  `expected start_tag` error when I use it on another server other than localhost.

My webservices are hosted perfectly by my company's server but it gives this expected start tag error in Android 2.2 emulator and displays nothing (null error) in toast.

I am not sure but it can be the 'NetworkOnMainThread' exception in phone(Android 4.0).

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, I kept getting an exception “Permission Denied” from `envelop.getResponse`.

I assumed something was wrong with my SOAP request and tried a number of changes to the envelop. Eventually after looking through some other boards I realized I needed an additional permission for android to allow this.

So add the following permission to your Android app's manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
```

Comment: error mentioned in the question is different from what you are actually providing the solution...